# Merge tuples in list with similar elements

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

I have to merge all the tuples containing atleast one element of each other.

```
tups=[(1,2),(2,3),(8,9),(4,5),(15,12),(9,6),(7,8),(3,11),(1,15)]
```

first tuple (1,2) should be merged with (2,3),(3,11),(1,15),(15,12) since each of these tuples contains similar items of the preceding tuple. so the final ouput should be

```
lst1 = [1,2,3,11,12,15]
lst2=[6,7,8,9] since (8,9),(9,6) and (7,8) have matching elements
```

My code so far:

```
finlst=[]
for items in range(len(tups)):
    for resid in range(len(tups)):
        if(tups[items] != tups[resid] ):
            if(tups[items][0]==tups[resid][0] or tups[items][0]==tups[resid][1]):
                finlst.append(list(set(tups[items]+tups[resid])))
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why should `(1,15)` be merged with `(3, 11)`? `(1,15)` has none of the same elements as `(3, 15)`, whilst `(3,11)` has none of the same elements as the first element `(1, 2)`. So I would say the logic is not clear here. Are you trying to do something where the last match becomes the basis for the next match (e.g. `(1,2) -> (2, 3) -> (3, 4)`) or are you basing all matches off the first tuple (e.g. `(1, 2) -> (2, 5) -> (6, 1)`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this, using sets that are expanded with matching tuples:

```
tups = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (8, 9), (4, 5), (15, 12), (9, 6), (7, 8), (3, 11), (1, 15)]

groups = []
for t in tups:
    for group in groups:
        # find a group that has at least one element in common with the tuple
        if any(x in group for x in t):
            # extend the group with the items from the tuple
            group.update(t)
            # break from the group-loop as we don’t need to search any further
            break
    else:
        # otherwise (if the group-loop ended without being cancelled with `break`)
        # create a new group from the tuple
        groups.append(set(t))


# output
for group in groups:
    print(group)
```

```
{1, 2, 3, 11, 15}
{8, 9, 6, 7}
{4, 5}
{12, 15}
```

---

Since this solution iterates the original tuple list *once* and in order, this will not work for inputs where the connections are not directly visible. For that, we could use the following solution instead which uses [fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration) to combine the groups for as long as that still works:

```
tups = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 4)]

import itertools

groups = [set(t) for t in tups]
while True:
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(groups, 2):
        # if the groups can be merged
        if len(a & b):
            # construct new groups list
            groups = [g for g in groups if g != a and g != b]
            groups.append(a | b)

            # break the for loop and restart
            break
    else:
        # the for loop ended naturally, so no overlapping groups were found
        break
```

Comment: this fails when the tups list is tups = [(1, 2),(3,4),(1,4)], the expected output was {1,2,3,4}, However ur code returns {1, 2, 4}, {3, 4}

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, it's more of graph theory problem related to connectivity, [Connectivity-Graph Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory))

We can use NetworkX for this, it's pretty much guaranteed to be correct:

```
def uniqueGroup(groups):
#     grp=[]
#     for group in groups:
#         grp.append(list(group))
#     l=groups

    import networkx 
    from networkx.algorithms.components.connected import connected_components


    def to_graph(groups):
        G = networkx.Graph()
        for part in groups:
            # each sublist is a bunch of nodes
            G.add_nodes_from(part)
            # it also imlies a number of edges:
            G.add_edges_from(to_edges(part))
        return G

    def to_edges(groups):
        """ 
            treat `l` as a Graph and returns it's edges 
            to_edges(['a','b','c','d']) -> [(a,b), (b,c),(c,d)]
        """
        it = iter(groups)
        last = next(it)

        for current in it:
            yield last, current
            last = current    

    G = to_graph(groups)
    return connected_components(G)
```

Output:

```
tups = [(1, 2),(3,4),(1,4)]
uniqueGroup(tups)

{1, 2, 3, 4}
```